# Docker compose networking only works on Mac not Ubuntu Linux

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, pgadmin

I have the following compose file

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: "postgres:12.4"
    ports:
      - "15432:5432"
    env_file:
      - ./db/database.env
    volumes:
      - ./db/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./db/init:/init
      - ./db/init/run.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/initialise.sh
  pgadmin:
    container_name: pgadmin4_container
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    network_mode: bridge
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: xxx
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: xxx
    ports:
      - "5050:80"
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
```

Now when I run this locally on my Mac, all is good. I get a database which my node API can reach on `localhost`, and I get a pgadmin, which can connect to the database by using `host.docker.internal`.

When I run this on ubuntu linux, however, pgadmin tells me it can't connect to the database. Bear in a mind the non-docker node api can connect to the db just fine on `localhost`.

I've tried:

1. with and without the extra-hosts bit
2. on pgadmin trying to connect to the db with 'localhost', '127.0.0.1', 'host.docker.internal', '172.17.0.1' and the public IP
3. changing network mode to bridge, host and removing it entirely, all while testing the aforementioned host names.

Comment: Why are you using `host.docker.internal` to try to communicate between containers?  You should be able to use the Compose service name `db` as a host name (see [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation).  Delete the `network_mode:`, `container_name:`, and `extra_hosts:` lines, they're all unnecessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a minimal setup that works. You can use it as a starting point:

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: "postgres:12.4"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "password"

  pgadmin:
    image: "dpage/pgadmin4"
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: xxx@xxx.xxx
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: xxxxxx
    ports:
      - "5050:80"
```

Then navigate to `http://localhost:5050` and login with `xxx@xxx.xxx / xxxxxx`.

Add a new server where the host is `db` (service name in docker-compose.yml), user is `postgres` and password is `password` (set in docker-compose.yml).

Notes:

You use `pgadmin` to access the database so no need to expose database ports.

Services see each other by name: pgadmin and db in your case.

Services run on a separate, "hidden" network and you only access to that is through a mapped port: 5050 in this case.